# How do I force oauth authentication to be against a specific user

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I'm following the client side authentication as described at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

I am routinely signed on to multiple Google accounts. Normally, the flow will prompt me to choose which account I want to authenticate with. However there are sometimes instances where it assumes the first account I signed in with, which is *not* the account I wish to use.

When users register with my service, they do so with a specific email address (and google id).

How do I qualify the oauth dialogue such that it will always take place using only the specified user?

On https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth I can see a comment...

```
Note: If you want to use the user_id parameter to select the current user from
 (potentially) multiple logged-in accounts,
 also add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email.
```

The implies that there is a user_id parameter I can include in the oauth call, but I can't see it documented anywhere, and there is nowhere in the Javascript API where I can inject a user_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the user_id parameter to your Authorization URI.

```
 gapi.auth.authorize({..., user_id: 'ali@gmail.com'}, handleAuthResult);
```

Comment: fantastic. Thx Ali

Can the user_id be the Google ID instead of the email address? Is this paramter documented somewhere so I can update my bookmarks?